# Supremum of a set proof.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $a$ be a real number and let $S={x\in\Bbb Q:x<a}$. Prove that $a=\sup⁡(S)$.

This obvious that $S$ is bounded above by $a$, and I know that by the completeness axiom, the least upper bound of $S$ exists. If I can show that $a$ is that least upper bound, then I'm done. I wonder if anyone can enlighten me on this problem.

Comment: Let $b = \sup S$. Since $a$ is an upper bound, you know $b \leqslant a$. Suppose you had $b < a$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? From what you said, it only show that $a$ is an upper bound but not the least upper bound, I haven't seen any contradiction yet.

Comment: You get a contradiction if you assume that the least upper bound were smaller than $a$. Alternatively (equivalently), show that for all $c < a$, there is an $x \in S$ with $x > c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing $b = \sup (S)$(the least upper bound exists and can be shown from any standard set of axioms). Now, exactly one of $b<a, b = a, b > a$ is true. Since $a$ is an upper bound, we clearly cannot have $b > a$. Supposing we had $b < a$. By the Archimedian property, we know that there exist rational numbers between $b$ and $a$. So, supposing $r$ was such a rational number. That is, $b<r<a$. Then $r < a \Longrightarrow r\in S$(by the definition of $S$) but since we assumed $b$ to be the least upper bound of $S$, we have $r\le b$ which contradicts $r > b$. So, the only alternative is $b=a$ which is what we wanted to show.